# How to change color row of table when click and save changes

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

i am using laravel, i have a list of letters, i want to when i clicked on row, background color of that row changes.

im doing this with ajax.

this is my ajax: [Ajax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jK59.png)

this is my letter_table : [letter table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnEr6.png)

i have `read_letter` with two numbers `0,1` with default value `0`, when value is `0` letter is  unread and when value is `1` letter is read.

this is my view for letter list : [Letter list view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44gCj.png)

and this is view of letter list in browser when i dont open any letter : [letter list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQ3F0.png)

and this is view of letter when i open letter : [letter list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOc00.png)

but my problem is when i clicked on other letters, it doesnt work, just on first item of the list working well.

this is my controller : [update read_letter in database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEnN5.png)

Edit : here is codes

ajax :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
$("#update_ajax").on('click', function () {
    var letter_id = $(this).data('id');
    var read_letter = 1;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/Letter/changeRead",
        data: {'letter_id': letter_id, 'read_letter': read_letter},
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data.success);
        }
    });
});
```

});

update letter_read in letterController :

```
public function updateLetterRead(Request $request)
{
    $letter = Letter::find($request->letter_id);
    $letter->read_letter = $request->read_letter;
    $letter->save();
    return response()->json(['success' => 'نامه خانده شد']);
}
```

button for show letter :

```
<td>
    <a href="{{ route('Letter.show',$letter->id) }}"
             data-id="{{ $letter->id }}"
             id="update_ajax">
             <i class="fas fa-eye"></i>
    </a>
</td>
```

Comment: Write the actual code into the question instead of images. Otherwise you will get downvoted in 2 seconds

Comment: Please update your question with code embed and let us know when done

Comment: question updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its happening because you are triggering for id and its coming multiple times in view. So convert it as class.

"Id's are used to describe a HTML element uniquely". **[DOC](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-an-id-and-class-in-html/)**

So in jQuery update `$("#update_ajax")` to `$(".update_ajax")` and in view *remove* `id="update_ajax"` and add `class="update_ajax"`

Another Hack method is :

update `$("#update_ajax").on('click', function()` *To* `$('tbody').on("click","#update_ajax",function()` But above suggestion is the right and need to be the selected one.

Answer (score 1):

The `#update_ajax` id is repeating for every row of the table. HTML ids should be unique.

Change the id to a class:

```
<td>
    <a href="{{ route('Letter.show',$letter->id) }}"
             data-id="{{ $letter->id }}"
             class="update_ajax">
             <i class="fas fa-eye"></i>
    </a>
</td>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
$(".update_ajax").on('click', function () {
    var letter_id = $(this).data('id');
    var read_letter = 1;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/Letter/changeRead",
        data: {'letter_id': letter_id, 'read_letter': read_letter},
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data.success);
        }
    });
});
```